# How do I process files itself as a Item?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oracle11g, spring-batch

I'm new to Spring Batch and I have the following requirement. I need to process a zip file that contains PDF, XML and .hsh files. For each XML and PDF, I have an .hsh file that contains their respective hashcodes. So, I need to take the hashcode and look at which file has the same hashcode and then register it in the database. How could I implement this solution using the chunk-oriented processing model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ResourcesItemReader](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/file/ResourcesItemReader.html) is what you are looking for. It allows you to read items of type `org.springframework.core.io.Resource` which could be a file in your case.

What you can do is create a chunk-oriented step as follows:

- Item reader: a `ResourcesItemReader` that loops over your hash file
- Item processor: given a hash file, determine which pdf/xml files correspond to the current hash
- Item writer: writes whatever needs to be written in your database

A couple of hints:

- You can define a class that represents a set of related files (hash + pdf + xml) as output type of your processor and input type for the writer. Encapsulation for the win!
- You can pre-load a Hashmap (hash -> file) and use it in the processor to get the corresponding file (xml or pdf) for a given hash.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I'll folow your adivce,